# How to change the position of the show password icon in layout

Tags: android

I want to change the position of the eye-icon to the left.

[image: inputype of edittext as textPassword]

I'm developing an Arabic app, so the text inside the EditText will be aligned to the right. Any idea on how to do this?

My code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Make Gravity of the edittext to right. and use drawableleft to align the icon to the left

Comment: @Madhav but i'm not using a drawable, that eye-icon is added when i use the inputType as textPassword

Answer (score 1):

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:text="Name"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_in"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"/>
```

Comment: but how would i set the icon to show the password text when the user clicks on it

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
<EditText 
 android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="right"
 android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>
```

Comment: it works with the drawableLeft thanks, but i'm using android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout library and it adds that eye-icon automatically

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textColorHint="@color/loginHint">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
    android:minWidth="350dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_store_white_48dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/loginHint"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: still aligned to the right, by the way i'm using android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout and it adds that icon automatically

Comment: I changed the android:drawableRight to android:drawableLeft, and it works but i assumed that i will have to provide a function so the icon can be used to show the password text right ?

Comment: it works but it is just an icon aligned to the left, i want to add the functionality of showing and hiding the password text

Comment: when i change the inputType to textPassword the eye-icon came again, i used  app:passwordToggleEnabled="false" to hide the eye-icon but now i want to use the drawable icon in your code to show and hide the password text, any idea

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:gravity="right"` in `EditText`, the text inside the `EditText` will be aligned to the right.